# How to run written code in codeshare.io?

Tags: javascript, python, build, share

Does anyone know how to run code on [codeshare.io](http://codeshare.io)? I figured out how to write it, but not run it... Can you even do that?

This site seems like such a perfect tool, and this is the one thing that I haven't got yet. I'm sure it's simple and this is a noob question, but thanks anyways!

Comment: It looks like it's only suppose to share code, not run it. You can share in all kinds of languages, including ones that can't run directly in a browser.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that, but I've seen screenshots that show a console window in it...

Comment: You might be seeing the Javascript console. Hit F12 then click on the Console tab. See if that looks similar.

Comment: ok, I'll give that a shot

Comment: That's baked into the browser and lets you run any Javascript (assuming the engine supports it), anywhere. So you could share *Javascript* through CodeShare then copy+paste it into that browser to run it. But that only works for Javascript.

Comment: lots of other sandbox sites you can run code in

Comment: Yeah, I know. I was just wondering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CodeShare doesn't have the feature to run the code.

Try using Codepad instead which does the same as codeshare and allows you to run the code also. https://codepad.remoteinterview.io

Comment: This service requires registration, but "Signup failed, Please use your work email to signup." (tried both sign up with email and google)